# Applications using GPL code and run-time libraries of proprietary IDEs

Tags: open-source, gpl, ide, closed-source

The GPL is described as a 'highly viral' license (if an application contains code which is licensed under GPL, distribution requires open sourcing of the whole application).

Do I understand correctly that linking **GPL code** with **closed source run-time libraries** provided by many commercial integrated software development environments has the effect that ***no (external/public) distribution*** of the resulting application is possible, simply because the closed source run-time libraries are not under GPL?

Comment: Distribution to *who*? Within an organization? or to the world at large?

Comment: @MichaelT external distribution, not only company-internal use

Comment: Yes, your understanding is essentially correct.  Your characterization "provided by many commercial integrated software environments" is a bit vague, but probably doesn't matter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a bit more nuanced than a straight up yes or no.

In general, it is correct that you must be able (and legally allowed) to distribute the source code of *all* libraries that are used in a program that contains GPL licensed code.

The nuance comes when dealing with GPL licensed code and libraries that are part of the core infrastructure of a computer (OS Kernel, windowing system, etc.) and libraries that implement a standard interface. Under GPL, those libraries are exempt from the viral nature of the GPL.
The standard libraries for the major programming languages are likely to be intended to fall under this exemption, so I wouldn't worry too much when using a piece of GPL code in your Windows application written using Visual Studio.

Comment: GPLv2 does have an exception: [However, as a special exception, the source code distributed need not include anything that is normally distributed (in either source or binary form) with the major components (compiler, kernel, and so on) of the operating system on which the executable runs, unless that component itself accompanies the executable.](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.html)

Comment: Moreover, even the [GNU GPLv1](http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/gpl-1.0.html) had it (see section 3). It was clarified a bit in the third version (as well as many other terms was), but nothing was changed essentialy.